# What is the German translation for intertwiner?

Tags: translation, rt.representation-theory

I'm searching for a translation for the term "intertwiner" in German.

Comment: Have you tried looking at some papers by German representation theorists who use the technique?

Comment: It is amusing to recall once seeing some book in English published in maybe about 1950 whose author explained that there's no English word corresponding to the German word _Faltung_, so that was what he used.  Apparently _convolution_ became standard more recently than that.

Comment: A related post on [math.se]: [Intertwiner in german?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172408) (From 2012 - later than this question.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I (native speaker) learned the term "Vertauschungsoperator" in my undergraduate courses. Unfortunately I cannot cite any reference right now, except the fact that the lecturer of the courses, Prof H.S. Holdgruen, is very sensible in his use of the german language. Therefore I estimate the probability very high that this is a common term in german texts on representation theory.

Comment: I can confirm that this is standard terminology in the German representation theory community (at least as far as I can tell from the members I know). The only reference I know by heart, however, is the German PhD thesis of Martin Olbrich.

Answer (score 4):

I think it can be translated as Verketter or Vermittler. See e.g. Karl-Henning Rehren's [Konforme Quantenfeldtheorie](https://web.archive.org/web/20070610230316/http://www.theorie.physik.uni-goettingen.de/%7Erehren/ps/cqft.pdf) on p.128. But I should warn that I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Personally (and I am a a native speaker) I have never heard about *Verketter* or *Vermittler*. I would just say *G-äquivariante Abbildung*.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I was already surprised that a google search for these words didn't give many results.

Comment: Anyway, in the PDF I'm referring to, it denotes a linear operator $V$ such that $V \rho(A) = \sigma(A) V$ for two representations of an algebra $A$, so the setting is slightly different.

Comment: @Pieter: On the numbered page 126 in the PDF, one finds "als Intertwiner bezeichnet (Verketter, Vermittler)".   To me it seems easiest just to use "Intertwiner" even if it's not quite an echt German word.   In mathematics, technical terms seem to migrate frequently across linguistic lines not covered by dictionaries.

Comment: Pieter: What's the difference to "$G$-equivariant"? Or "$G$-homomorphism"?

Comment: The PDF I was referring to deals about representations of $C^*$ algebras, not of group representations, so $G$-equivariant is not really appropriate in that context.

Comment: This is indeed the translation with the longest history. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172408/intertwiner-in-german/172426#172426